# Using Spring Ldap I need to create a subContext to an already created context

Tags: spring-ldap

I am using Spring core 2.0.2. When I call 'context.createSubContext()' I get a 'not implemented' error. When I look at the Spring Ldap core source for LdapTemplate I see that it isn't implemented.

So how do I create a subContext in Spring Ldap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DirContextAdapter` is intended to simplify working with attribute values, not interacting with the LDAP tree (see [reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/#dirobjectfactory)). You should use `LdapTemplate` instead - more specifically, in this case, the [`bind`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapOperations.html#bind(org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations)) operation.

Comment: Thank you sir, that is what I ended up doing. Thank you for the clarification!